# Is prototype pattern the right fit here?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

I have an array of type `Cell`. This is a 2D array.
Depending on certain conditions, I might have to resize this array and shift the `Cell` objects one row or column down/right/left.

I was thinking of using the prototype pattern to copy the original array into another larger array.

Does this offer any more benefits over simply doing an array resize?

Edit: I realized that I have not mentioned my intent. I don't really need another object. I just want a larger array based on certain conditions.

Comment: How this will help you? Coping prototype is basically cloning, but you want different object.

Comment: @Andrey, Updated the original question.

Comment: There may be better ways of doing this such has having a cell belong to a row list and a column list. This could allow a row to be inserted without having to update all of the items. This could be much cheaper if this is a frequent operation.

Comment: @Chriseyre2000, You do have a good point! Yes, this is a pretty frequent operation.

Comment: So have an ordered list of column and row objects that themselves have lists of cells that refer back to the container to get the current index. Columns are much cheaper to move this way. And if it's a sparce array (or can have a sensible default) you only need to set cells that have changed.

Comment: @Chriseyre2000, Can you please elaborate in an answer. I am sorry I am getting a bit lost...

Answer (score 1):

The only reason this could be of help is if you are making a *shallow* copy: copying would save you the costs of creating new objects. The flip side of it is that all `Cell` objects inside the array would be shared among multiple 2D arrays; if this presents a problem, you should go back to creating arrays from scratch.

Comment: There are no issues in sharing the `Cell` objects - as I have mentioned in the intent, I basically need a new object. The advantage of shallow copy had not crossed my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer No.

There is an alternative solution that will solve your problem without needing a prototype.

Don't store the cells in an array.
The cells don't know their row and column numbers but instead ask the row/column for it.
This allows the columns to be rearranged without having to update every item.

Have a container object that represents the array and can return the cell at a given (x,y) coordinate. If the array is sparce (or if it has a sensible default) then treat a missing cell as the default. This will massively reduce storage costs.
The columns and rows belong to the container. Adding an empty row or column now becomes a case of inserting a row or column object.

Comment: It sounds good. In my earlier implementation, I was planning to make a 2D matrix with `Cell`. I could access each cell with its index. For determining the cell at x,y - I plan to introdude two variables `offsetX` and `offsetY` to `Cell`. Now shifting will involve changing these in each object. Was this what you had in mind?

Comment: I was suggesting that the offset belong to a seperate column or row object that is referenced by the cell. This means that inserting a new row only requires adding a row to the list of rows and updating the row offset on moved rows.